# Tiling in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with data `[3, 5]`, and I want to create a function which takes this array, and returns the following (2 x 3 x 2) NumPy array :

```
[[[3, 3],
  [3, 3],
  [3, 3]],

 [[5, 5],
  [5, 5],
  [5, 5]]]
```

However, I have not been able to achieve this, using Numpy's `repeat()` or `tile()` functions.

For example:

```
x = np.array([3, 5])
y = np.repeat(x, [2, 3, 2])
```

Gives the following error:

```
ValueError: a.shape[axis] != len(repeats)
```

And:

```
x = np.array([3, 5])
y = np.tile(x, [2, 3, 2])
```

Creates a (2 x 3 x 4) array:

```
[[[3, 5, 3, 5],
  [3, 5, 3, 5],
  [3, 5, 3, 5]],

 [[3, 5, 3, 5],
  [3, 5, 3, 5],
  [3, 5, 3, 5]]]
```

What should my function be?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np. tile`, you just miss dividing by the number of elements at repetition axis,  in your case it's **1D**

```
x = np.array([3, 5])
y = np.tile(x, [2, 3, 2 // x.shape[0]])
```

---

```
def get_nd(a, shape):

  shape = np.array(shape)

  a_shape = np.ones_like(shape)
  a_shape[-a.ndim:] = a.shape

  shape = (shape * 1/a_shape).astype('int')

  return np.tile(a, shape)
```

---

```
get_nd(x, (2, 3, 2))
```

---

### Update

Transpose desired shape, if you are targeting `(2, 3, 6)`, then ask for `(6, 3, 2)` then transpose the resultant matrix

```
get_nd(x, (2, 3, 6)).T
```

---

Or use the following function instead

```
def get_nd_rep(a, shape):

  shape = np.array(shape)

  x_shape = np.ones_like(shape)
  x_shape[-a.ndim:] = a.shape

  shape = (shape * 1/x_shape).astype('int')

  return np.tile(a, shape).T
```

---

```
get_nd_rep(x, (2, 3, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does give me a (2 x 3 x 2) array. However, it just gives 6 rows of `[3, 5]`, whereas I require 3 rows of `[3, 3]`, followed by 3 rows of `[5, 5]`.

Comment: You could use transpose, `.T`

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
import operator as op

DIM = (2, 3, 2)  # size of each dimension
CAP = reduce(op.mul, DIM[1:])  # product of DIM

x = np.array([3, 5])
y = np.repeat(x, CAP).reshape(*DIM)
```

This will generate a 2x3 array of each element of `x`, repeated.

DIM[0] should be `len(x)`; otherwise, an exception will be raised. This is due to the parameter of `np.reshape` being incompatible with the shape produced by `np.repeat` ([numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)).

This is also the reason why the `ValueError` was raised in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `repeat`:  `np.repeat(a, repeats, axis=None)`

It can be used as:

```
In [345]: np.repeat(x, [2,3])                                                                        
Out[345]: array([3, 3, 5, 5, 5])
```

In other words, if the repeats is a list, it should match `a` in size, saying how many times each element is repeated.

While we could expand the dimensions of `x`, and try repeats (or tile), a simpler approach is to just expand `x`, and reshape:

```
In [349]: np.repeat(x,6)                                                                             
Out[349]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
In [350]: np.repeat(x,6).reshape(2,3,2)                                                              
Out[350]: 
array([[[3, 3],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 3]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 5]]])
```

### multiple repeats

Another approach is to expand `x` to 3d, and apply 2 repeats.  I had to try several things before I got it right:

```
In [357]: x[:,None,None]                                                                             
Out[357]: 
array([[[3]],

       [[5]]])
In [358]: x[:,None,None].repeat(2,2)                                                                 
Out[358]: 
array([[[3, 3]],

       [[5, 5]]])
In [359]: x[:,None,None].repeat(2,2).repeat(3,1)                                                     
Out[359]: 
array([[[3, 3],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 3]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 5]]])
```

### tile

`np.tile` does something similar (multiple repeats):

```
In [361]: np.tile(x[:,None,None],(1,3,2))                                                            
Out[361]: 
array([[[3, 3],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 3]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 5]]])
```

To use `repeat` or `tile` I usually need to review the docs and/or try several things.  Especially when expanding the dimensions.

### broadcasting

The problem is even simpler with `broadcasting`:

```
In [370]: res = np.zeros((2,3,2), int)                                                               
In [371]: res[:] = x[:,None,None]                                                                    
In [372]: res                                                                                        
Out[372]: 
array([[[3, 3],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 3]],

       [[5, 5],
        [5, 5],
        [5, 5]]])
```

though getting the expansion of `x` dimensions right took a few tries.